# Call Magento SOAP inside Meteor method invoked by the client

Tags: javascript, magento, meteor, soap

I'm using zardak:soap package in Meteor to connect with Magento SOAP v2 API. I've created a file inside the 'server' folder where I create a soap connection on Meteor.startup. Then I run a ticker that invokes random soap method every 30sec just to keep the connection up.

```
let soapConnection;

Meteor.startup(() => {
    soapConnection = createAPIConnection('http://magento.site.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1', {username: 'user', apiKey: 'password'});
});

function createAPIConnection(url, credentials) {
    try {
        let client = Soap.createClient(url);

        let loginResult = client.login(credentials);
        let sessionId = loginResult.loginReturn.$value;

        return {
            conn: client,
            sessionId: sessionId
        };

    } catch (e) {
        if (e.error === 'soap-creation') {
            console.log('SOAP Client creation failed');
        }

        return null;
    }
}

function tick() {
    try {
        soapConnection.conn.catalogCategoryInfo({
            sessionId: soapConnection.sessionId,
            categoryId: 1
        }, (err, result) => { });

    } catch (e) { }
}
```

Then I have a Meteor method that is called from the client. When it is called, the soap method call fails and I'm getting a 'soap error' message in console.

```
Meteor.methods({
'createMagentoCustomer'(customer) {
        try {
            soapConnection.conn.customerCustomerCreate({
                sessionId: soapConnection.sessionId,
                customerData: customer
            }, (err, res) => {
                if (err)
                    console.log('soap error');
                else
                    console.log(res);
            });

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('SOAP Method <customerCustomerCreate> call failed');
        }
    },
});
```

So, the ticker works well with no problems, but when I try to call soap via Meteor method, it fails. Notice that the soapConnection method is not null and I do receive error in the soap method callback.

Any suggestions?

Meteor version 1.3.4.1